# Remove toolbar elevation for specific fragment

Tags: android, toolbar, elevation

How can I set Elevation to 0 or disable it for a specific Fragment of my `NavigationDrawer`? Programmatically or with theme maybe ?

`toolbar.setElevation(0)` seems not working.

This ìn my `onNavigationItemSelected` doesn't work, elevation won't change :

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_menu_account) {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
} else {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(8);
    }
}
```

And there is my Coordinator layout with Toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**RESOLVED - Thanks to Amir ! Work with this in my `onNavigationItemSelected`**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_menu_account) {
         appBar.setElevation(0);
    } else {
         appBar.setElevation(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you should set Appbar elevation to zero.

Comment: I have tried see my edit. Actually it doesn't work..

Comment: can you past your xml ?

Comment: See my edit, add my CoordinatorLayout with Toolbar

Comment: set Id for your **Appbar** and set elevation for you appBar instead of Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

To remove shadow in Toolbar use

`app:elevation="0"` in AppBarLayout xml or

use `mAppBarLayout.setTargetElevation(0)` in java.

It worked for me.